# Inject deployed context into Integration test

Tags: junit, integration-testing, inject, apache-tomee, maven-failsafe-plugin

I am running JUnit integration tests using maven-failsafe-plugin. I have created a profile which :
a. install TomEE
b. build project war
c. deploy it on TomEE
d. start server instance

Above works fine, however I want to inject the deployed context into tests. The tests are running in separate JVM than the TomEE server.

I came across framework Arquilian which,
'Arquillian can inject the deployed Contexts and Dependency Injection (CDI) beans, Enterprise JavaBeans (EJB) components and other Java EE resources directly to your tests'.